# CodeIgniter. Where are some of the basic classes located?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just have started working with codeIgniter and want to know how things in CodeIgniter?
such as

1. Where is this extended class located?

   ```
   class Mystations extends CI_Controller{
   //--- class content }
   ```
2. Where can find "load" and "model" ?

   ```
   $this->load->model('user_model');
   ```
3. Though I'm aware of using CI active queries, I don't know how things work in background or where mysql_conect is used in CI.

Comment: Ever considered reading CIs manual/documentation? They probably have one.

Comment: I usually grep for stuff I can't find.  I've learned more about frameworks that way then from RTFM.

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide best documented framework probably; also, check the core/ folder, everything is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the source is hosted on GitHub, you can search the actual code to find what you're after.  For instance:

1. [CI_Controller search](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=repo%3aEllisLab/CodeIgniter%20CI_Controller&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=) : [result](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/a920fbe473ba265f86c974f4c4d1b95ad0fdb2b8/system/core/Controller.php)  (`system/core/Controller.php`)
2. [function model search](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=repo%3aEllisLab/CodeIgniter%20%22function%20model%22&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=) : [result](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/d56be70257696d0bbf2dcc880888d8dc17cba21c/system/core/Loader.php)  (`system/core/Loader.php`)
3. [mysqli connnect search](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=repo%3aEllisLab/CodeIgniter%20mysqli&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=) : [result](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/bb2e2ed4ac4200c12dae08018e932c65256e8701/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php) (`system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php`)

Answer (score 1):

1. Your own extended libraries lies in `application/libraries`. [Read about extending here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html#footer).
2. This question is rather unclear. Your models lies in `application/models`. [Read about models here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html).
3. You connect to your database through `config/database.php` by providing your settings. You autoload it in `config/autoloads.php`.

Note that my answer mostly consists of refering to CodeIgniters User Guide. Their guides are really good and helps you very far on your own.

CodeIgniter + Google + knowing what to search for = Success!

Comment: I think he wants to know 1) Codeigniter.php 2)core/Loader.php and 3) the various DB driver